# Unwanted Facebook button at first time use of my FB application in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am playing around with facebook application, making them in iframe using coldfusion.
Following is the url of my app http://apps.facebook.com/firstones/

Instead of going directly going to the permissions page, it goes to the page shown below in picture. 
[image: View that I get when use the application first time]

And after clicking on that big 'Facebook' button it goes to ask for applications permission. And once permissions are granted it takes to my website, where I have hosted the application, instead of opening it in Facebook only.

Following is the code of my canvas url [http://www.dkyadav.com/firstOnes/auth/]

*index.cfm*

```
<cfparam name="client_id" default="1234"> <!---same as app_id --->
<cfparam name="redirect_uri" default="http://www.dkyadav.com/firstOnes/auth/">
<cfparam name="redirect_uri_final" default="http://www.dkyadav.com/firstOnes/">
<cfparam name="scope" default="user_education_history,user_hometown,friends_education_history ">
<cfparam name="client_secret" default="56789"> <!---- App_secret key ---->


<cfif not isdefined('url.code')>
    <Cflocation url="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=#client_id#&redirect_uri=#redirect_uri#&scope=#scope#" >

<Cfelse>
    <Cfif isdefined('url.error')>
        <Cfoutput>
            #url.error#<br />
            Access denied.
        </Cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
        <cfoutput>#url.code#<br />
            <cfhttp url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" result="token">
                <cfhttpparam name="client_id" value="#client_id#" encoded="no" type="url">
                <cfhttpparam name="redirect_uri" value="#redirect_uri#" encoded="no" type="url">
                <cfhttpparam name="client_secret" value="#client_secret#" encoded="no" type="url">
                <cfhttpparam name="code" value="#url.code#" encoded="no" type="url">
            </cfhttp>
            <cflocation url="#redirect_uri_final#?#token.filecontent#" addtoken="no">
        </cfoutput>
    </Cfif>
</cfif>
```

And in http://www.dkyadav.com/firstOnes/index.cfm I look for access_token and have rest of my application.

I does the above said things only for the first time it run. Once its permission get approved, it works normally as expected.

You can try out this app running yourself http://apps.facebook.com/firstones/
Please help and let me know what I am actually missing. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I dont need access_token, I just need oauth_token that I get by Decoding the result I got from submitting my client_id to 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth....'

Below is the code that I am using:

```
<cfif isdefined('signed_request')>
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset b64 = signed_request>
        <!--- Split the param by the . --->
        <cfset raw_str = ListGetAt(b64, 2, ".")>
        <cfset res = Len(raw_str) % 4>
        <cfif res eq 2>
             <cfset raw_str &= "==">
        <cfelseif res eq 3>
             <cfset raw_str &= "=">
        </cfif>
        <!--- Base 64 Decode --->
        <cfset result = ToString(BinaryDecode(raw_str, "Base64"))>
        <!--- String to JSON --->
        <cfset json = DeserializeJSON(result)>

        <cfif StructKeyExists(json,'oauth_token')>

        <Cfset at = json.oauth_token>

            <cfhttp url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=#at#" result="newsFeed" />

            <cfif IsJSON(newsFeed.filecontent)>
                <cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(newsFeed.filecontent)>
                <cfdump var = #cfData#>
            <cfelse>
                filecontent not in json format   
            </cfif>
        <cfelse>
            <script>
                top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345XXX&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/test_app/&scope=read_stream,email'
            </script>
        </cfif>

    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you have is that your initial display page on Facebook is actually bursting out of the iframe.

You can see the Javascript doing that on http://www.dkyadav.com/firstOnes/index.cfm in the `fbLogin()` function:

```
top.location.href = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?...
```

`top` refers to the window at the top of your window hierarchy which in your case will mean the actual Facebook home page with the iframe in it.

Hope that helps!